# NGINX cannot reach domain defined by server_name

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I cannot access domain `my-domain.xyz` defined for the backend server `localhost:4000` inside a docker container (service name being `api`)

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
  api: # backend service name
    container_name: nhatot-backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./hosts:/etc/hosts
```

**conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my-domain.xyz; # does not work
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://api:4000; # route to backend
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

Only `localhost` is mapped to my backend, not `my-domain.xyz`.

What should I do so that my backend server is accessible via `my-domain.xyz`?

Comment: As a quick solution on your dev machine, add a line in your /etc/hosts file => `127.0.0.1 my-domain.xyz`. If this needs to be accessible from outside your own machine, configure an entry in the DNS server managing that domain to point to the target machine.

Comment: @Zeitounator with this approach, it keeps loading forever for some reasons

Comment: @WilliamLe did you find any solution? I have same problem

Comment: @parastoo unfortunately not yet, I must find myself another approach for the time being

Comment: I resolved it today on windows:
I added server_names on this path : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.test mydomain.test
@WilliamLe